# WPF: TwoWay binding is ALWAYS updated - OneWay binding is ONLY ONCE updated

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, oneway

I know what you think: It is 2017, please don't come up with this again, but I really can not find any valueable explanation for this.

Please have a look at the **ActiveNotes** property in this XAML-Code.

I have this TwoWay binding in my XAML, which works perfectly. It is ALWAYS updated, if the PropertyChanged event for ScaleNotes is fired and if the binding is set to TwoWay.

```
<c:Keyboard 
            Grid.Row="2" 
            Grid.Column="0" 
            PlayCommand="{Binding PlayCommand}" 
            StopCommand="{Binding StopCommand}" 
            ActiveNotes="{Binding ScaleNotes, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

The ScaleNotes property in the ViewModel looks like this. Whenever it changes, the PropertyChanged event is **guaranteed** to be fired. I checked and double checked it. The business logic in the ViewModel works.

```
private ReadOnlyCollection<eNote> _ScaleNotes;
public ReadOnlyCollection<eNote> ScaleNotes
{
    get { return _ScaleNotes; }
    set { SetField(ref _ScaleNotes, value); }
}

[DebuggerStepThrough]
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

[DebuggerStepThrough]
protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
    field = value;
    OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    return true;
}
```

Up to here everything is ok. Whenever the ScaleNotes property in the VM is changed, the target property ActiveNotes is updated.

**Now the problem:**

If I only change the binding in the XAML to OneWay and the business logic in the VM stays 100% the same, the ActivesNotes property in the target object **is updated only once** even if the PropertyChanged event is fired. I checked and double checked it. The PropertyChanged event for the ScaleNotes property is always fired.

```
<c:Keyboard 
            Grid.Row="2" 
            Grid.Column="0" 
            PlayCommand="{Binding PlayCommand}" 
            StopCommand="{Binding StopCommand}" 
            ActiveNotes="{Binding ScaleNotes, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Just to make this complete, here is DP in the target object.

```
public static DependencyProperty ActiveNotesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ActiveNotes", 
        typeof(ReadOnlyCollection<eNote>), 
        typeof(Keyboard), 
        new PropertyMetadata(OnActiveNotesChanged));


public ReadOnlyCollection<eNote> ActiveNotes
{
    get
    {
        return (ReadOnlyCollection<eNote>)GetValue(ActiveNotesProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(ActiveNotesProperty, value);
    }
}

private static void OnActiveNotesChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Keyboard keyboard    = (Keyboard)d;
    keyboard.ActiveNotes = (ReadOnlyCollection<eNote>)e.NewValue;

    if ((keyboard.ActiveNotes != null) && (keyboard.ActiveNotes.Count > 0))
    {
        keyboard.AllKeys.ForEach(k => { if ( k.Note != eNote.Undefined) k.IsActiveKey = true; });
        keyboard.AllKeys.ForEach(k => { if ((k.Note != eNote.Undefined) && (!keyboard.ActiveNotes.Contains(k.Note))) k.IsActiveKey = false; });
    }
    else
    {
        keyboard.AllKeys.ForEach(k => { if (k.Note != eNote.Undefined) k.IsActiveKey = true; });
    }
}
```

I don't understand this. From my knowledge, OneWay and TwoWay only define in which direction the values are updated and not how often they can be updated.

I can not understand, that everything works fine with TwoWay, the business logic stays 100% the same and OneWay is a deal breaker.

If you ask yourself, why I want to know this: This binding was planned as a OneWay binding. It makes no sense to update the source in any way. I only changed it to TwoWay, because OneWay doesn't work as expected.

**SOLUTION with the help of @MikeStrobel: (see comments)**

The code needs be changed this way:

```
private static void OnActiveNotesChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Keyboard keyboard    = (Keyboard)d;

    //THIS LINE BREAKED THE CODE, WHEN USING OneWay binding BUT NOT WITH TwoWay binding
    //keyboard.ActiveNotes = (ReadOnlyCollection<eNote>)e.NewValue;

    if ((keyboard.ActiveNotes != null) && (keyboard.ActiveNotes.Count > 0))
    {
        keyboard.AllKeys.ForEach(k => { if ( k.Note != eNote.Undefined) k.IsActiveKey = true; });
        keyboard.AllKeys.ForEach(k => { if ((k.Note != eNote.Undefined) && (!keyboard.ActiveNotes.Contains(k.Note))) k.IsActiveKey = false; });
    }
    else
    {
        keyboard.AllKeys.ForEach(k => { if (k.Note != eNote.Undefined) k.IsActiveKey = true; });
    }
}
```

Using a OneWay binding, the assignment in the OnActiveNotesChanged event handler method deletes or clears out the binding. Mike is correct saying, that the assingment is completely unnecessary, because at this point of time the value is already set before in the property. So it makes no sense at all, no matter if I use OneWay or TwoWay binding.

Comment: Looks like you’re setting a new local value for `ActiveNotes` in its DP change handler.  That would clear out a one-way binding, but not a two-way binding.  You don’t need to assign a DP in its own change handler—the new value has already been applied.

Comment: I will test it. Please give me 2 minutes.

Comment: @Mike Strobel This is the correct answer. If I delete the assignment in the DP OnActiveNotesChanged, it works as expected with OneWay. Please can you explain in an answer, what "clear out" means. Does it mean, it deletes the binding?

Comment: @MikeStrobel You already gave the right answer. Thanks a lot, you made my day. If you like, just write a seperate answer, so that I can give you the credits/points for it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dependency properties have a complex system of [precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence).  The value of a dependency property at any given time may come from various sources: bindings, style setters, trigger setters, etc.  Local values have the highest priority, and when you set a local value, you suppress values coming from other sources.

In the case of a binding, setting a local value will cause a source-to-target binding (`OneWay` or `OneTime`) to be ***removed***.  However, when you set a local value on a property with a target-to-source binding (`TwoWay` or `OneWayToSource`), the binding will be maintained, and the local value you assigned will get propagated back to the source.

In your case, the issue is here:

```
keyboard.ActiveNotes = (ReadOnlyCollection<eNote>)e.NewValue;
```

In your `OnActiveNotesChanged` handler, you're assigning a new local value to `ActiveNotes`, which is causing your `OneWay` binding to be removed.  Fortunately, the solution is simple: you can remove this line entirely, as it is redundant.   In most cases it is unnecessary to assign a dependency property in its own change handler—the new value has already been applied.  (And if you want an opportunity to replace a proposed value before it gets applied, the place to do that would be a `CoerceValueCallback`, which you can also specify in you `PropertyMetadata`.)

Comment: Brillant answer! Thank you, Mike. You made my day. At the same time I feel a bit ashamed, because I think it is such a beginners question. However - kudos to New York!

Comment: No need to feel ashamed.  WPF has a notoriously steep learning curve.  Reading the MSDN article I linked to will fill you in on some of the subtleties.  Anyway, glad I could help.

Comment: And as you already mentioned in the comments under the question: This code line did not make sense at all from the beginning. No matter if I use OneWay or TwoWay binding, because in the OnChanged event handler the new value is always already set before.

Answer (score 1):

Let me share my experience after spending sleepless nights on this issue!

I stumbled into this issue on a slightly different use case for which I could not find a solution, but thanks to the advice above I could finally solve it.

To put it short, I faced the same Binding dissociation issue but without having code behind accessing the incriminated property at all! The issue occurred on a `CustomControl`!

In fact, you must also be aware that if a `CustomControl` declares a `DependencyProperty` which is used in a `Binding` both by the **consumer** of the `CustomControl` and inside the **Template** of the `CustomControl`, then you **MUST** ensure that our **Binding** in the **Template** of the `CustomControl` is eighter of type `TemplateBinding` or a regular binding using `OneWay` or `OneWayToSource`.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsChecked", typeof(bool), typeof(QAToggle), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.None));

public bool IsChecked
{
    get => (bool)this.GetValue(IsCheckedProperty);
    set => this.SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value);
}
```

If not, the `Binding` used in the `UserControl`'s template when updating will also set a new value to the `CustomControl`s Property thus removing the external binding set up by the consumer of the `CustomControl`.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ccont:QAToggle}">
    
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"  Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight"            Value="23" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth"             Value="75" />
    
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>

            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ccont:QAToggle}">

                <ToggleButton x:Name            = "QAToggle"
                              Command           = "{TemplateBinding Command}" 
                              CommandParameter  = "{TemplateBinding CommandParameter}" 
                              FontSize          = "{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                              FontWeight        = "{TemplateBinding FontWeight}"
                              FontFamily        = "{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                              IsThreeState      = "False"
                              IsChecked         = "{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ccont:QAToggle}}">
```

Here the line `IsChecked = "{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ccont:QAToggle}}"` will break the external binding. To avoid this change it to:

```
IsChecked = "{TemplateBinding IsChecked}"
```

or

```
IsChecked = "{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ccont:QAToggle}, Mode=OneWay}"
```